# Iterate text from text file in a batch scripted for loop,

Tags: windows, batch-file

I wrote below batch script to read from a text file

```
@echo off
set FILE_PATH=C:\Users\atripathi\Desktop\test.txt
FOR /F %%W in(%FILE_PATH%) DO(
    set MYDIR=%%W
    FOR /F "tokens=2 delims=\" %%d in (test.txt) DO 
        echo app is %%d and %%W
    )
)
```

Suppose the text.txt has below text:

```
example_apps\loopback\workspace 
example_apps\adaptive_anc_lite_loopback\workspace
```

I want the output as:

```
app is loopback and example_apps\loopback\workspace
app is \adaptive_anc_lite_loopback and lexample_apps\adaptive_anc_lite_loopback\workpace
```

But I get the output as:

```
app is loopback and example_apps\loopback\workspace
app is adaptive_anc_lite_loopback and example_apps\loopback\workspace
app is loopback and example_apps\adaptive_anc_lite loopback\workspace
app is adaptive_enc_lite_loopback and example_apps-cadaptive__anc_lite
```

Comment: I get the OUTPUT AS:
app is loopback and example_apps\loopback\workspace
app is adaptive_anc_lite_loopback and example_apps\loopback\workspace 
app is loopback and example_apps\adaptive_anc_lite loopback\workspace 
app is adaptive_enc_lite_loopback and example_apps-cadaptive__anc_lite

Comment: _"But I get the output as:"_ yes, we 're listening?

Comment: @Gerhard Can you please help

Comment: @LetsBhonest, I've put the information from your comments into your question where it belongs! Please delete your, now not needed, comments above, and make any necessary adjustments directly within your question itself. There is a clear **[edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/63441566/edit)** link directly beneath your question which you should click on to use the edit facility. When you do start editing, please note that the code is not valid and will not output what you stated it outputs. There appears to be other typos, so it would assist potential helpers if you correct those too!

Comment: Besides some syntax errors (which are easy to find and correct), there is a logical error: your second loop iterates over (the same?) file (again?) (`in (test.txt) do`) instead of the result of the first loop (`in ("%%W") do`).

Answer (score 0):

Here is what I think you were trying to achieve. I'm not going to explain the code, as you have given me the impression that your only interest is in receiving a solution, not in how this site or the below code works.

```batch-file
@SetLocal EnableExtensions
@Set "FILE_PATH=%UserProfile%\Desktop\test.txt"
@For /F UseBackQ^ Delims^=^ EOL^= %%G In ("%FILE_PATH%")Do For /F Delims^=^ EOL^= %%H In ("%%~G\..")Do Echo app is %%~nxH and %%G
@Pause
```

Do not change anything at all in the code, it should only be tested exactly as it is, on its own, in a standalone batch file with a `.cmd` extension, and against a text file named `test.txt` on the current profiles' Desktop, and with the same content as the example in your question above.